# how to display PDF file in webBrowser contron in 64-bit winforms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have WebBrowser control in my Winforms application which is displaying the PDF file using the ceTe.DynamicPDF.20 to merge the PDF document into WebBrowser. When I run my application on 64-bit version the WebBrowser control is not displaying the PDF.
Is anyone know how to display the PDF file into 64-bit version?

Comment: Just an idea, does your library support 64-bit systems? You may have to download a specific library for both architectures.

Comment: Yes,If I set Target CPU as x86 it works fine.However If I set Target CPU as Any CPU the PDF is not displaying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying pdf in WinForms webbrowser control under x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904052/displaying-pdf-in-winforms-webbrowser-control-under-x64)

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without more details, but according to [this forum topic](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Forums/DisplayThread.csp?FD=28&ThreadID=2747) (scroll to the bottom for the useful part), you may need a different dll for the different architectures indeed. As for how to refer to the correct dll in both cases, you may wish to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762178/visual-studio-loading-the-right-x86-or-x64-dll).